# Why do my PHP sessions keep ending, and Apache occasionally crashes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

My JavaScript:

```
//Function that gets the chat from backend
function showmessage(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("chat").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/backend-display.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

//Show any messages that will pop-up
setInterval('showmessage()',400);


//Function that updates new rows
function newrows(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {

            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                var elem = document.getElementById('chat');
                elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","/test2.php?success=true"+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

//Updates new rows every x seconds
setInterval('newrows()',300);


//Backend to send a message
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var mes = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var message = "message=" +mes;

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/backend-input.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(message);
  document.forms["form"].reset();
}
```

PHP.ini config:

[Php.ini config link](https://pastebin.com/raw/LY8FXW64)

Backend for inputting:

```
<?php include 'auth.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$name = $_SESSION["name"];
$messageunfilter = $_POST["message"];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','chat');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


if(empty($_POST["message"])){
           echo "You must enter a message...";
           exit();
      }else{
           echo "success";
      }


//Checking SQL    
$check = array("\\", "'");
$change   = array("\\\\", "''");

$messagefilter = str_replace($check, $change, $messageunfilter);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="INSERT INTO `chat` (`id`, `username`, `message`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$messagefilter', '$current_date')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Backend for recieving messages from DB:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<?php //Selects all of the logged in users messages.
$name = $_SESSION["name"];

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','chat');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM `chat` ORDER BY date";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if( $numrows == "0" or !isset($_SESSION["name"])){
            echo "<div class='msg'>";
           echo "<div class='username_admin'>System</div>";
           echo "<div class='msg_admin'>There are no messages to display...</div>";
            echo "</div>";
           exit();
      }else{
           echo "";
      }


echo "<div class='msg_container'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $class_msg = "msg";
    $class_username = "username";
    $class_message = "message";

    if ($row['username'] == $_SESSION['name']) {
    $class_msg = "msg_user";
    $class_username = "username_user";
    $class_message = "message_user";
    }

    echo "<div class='$class_msg'>";
    echo "<div class='$class_username'><span>" . $row['username'] . "</span></div>";
    echo "<div class='$class_message'><span>" . $row['message'] . "</span></div>";
    echo "</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I am aware of websockets and my code needs to be cleaned up a lot, as well as the fact that my statements are not prepared.

For some reason after this system running for 5 minutes or so, the sessions seem to get destroyed?

I have no idea why this is? Is it because I am requesting it too many times?

Even if I have just 2 users connected messaging each other it still crashes, it can crash after 60 seconds, 1 minute?

Can someone please help me figure out why this is, I would be more than grateful.

**Thank you so much for even looking at this post, even that means a lot! (Sorry for the overload of code here, I just want to be sure that I am showing you everything I can!)**

Comment: see the apache logs for a possible error message

Comment: @MiSAKACHi The main problem is that my sessions keep getting destroyed, I think apache crashing was to do with something else as it only ever crashed once!

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments at the php docs for `session_start()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), it may be necessary to write to the session data in order to keep the session alive under some circumstances.

I would give adding `$_SESSION['time'] = time();` after your `session_start()`s a try and see if that helps.  I'm not sure what is causing the crash but I would check the apache error logs first.

Comment: How would this help keep the session alive, could you please explain to me a bit more, thank you very much!

Comment: It's just a guess based on the comment and your described behavior, but the commenters reasoning is an issue with filesystem mounting parameters and the mtime being updated instead of the atime.  By explicitly writing to the session data on each request, that should update the atime (I guess).